# What areas are good pivot targets if you want to avoid javascript?

Tags: software-development, career-switch

At work I write Javascript. Alot of javascript. ALL THINGS JAVASCRIPT.

Frontends: js

Backends: js

Tests: js

Db: js drivers

Documentation: js

Any problem that might come up: npm install (your favorite broken dependency)

I'm getting very sick of this. The business people don't really care, they just want things done quick. It's getting to the point that I'm thinking about maybe looking elsewhere for stuff to do (haven't decided), but...

What are some **areas in software development** that one can pivot to?, that satisfy:

- Fairly easy to migrate to, if one comes from a web backend dev direction, and is a fast learner. (since I think it's more or less impossible to stay in web-world if you want to avoid Javascript)
- Javascript is NOT the bread and butter of absolutely everything, and is kept to a minimum.
- Has some kind of future.

and what are some steps one can take to be more eligible for positions in these areas?

Comment: What is it about Javascript that you are seeking to avoid?

Comment: @jwh20 I quite like JS! But I mind the lock-in effect. All this JS focus has left me with very little documented professional experience with all other languages (documented, professional being key here). Also there are demand-supply issues, Everyone and their grandma writes JS. I also find that employer attitudes are often like this: (C++) => 'understands manual memory management, knows pointer arithmetic', while (JS) => 'script kiddo, with some JQuery at best'. I'd like employers to think: 'He's missing domain knowledge, but at least he knows Java', and not 'This guy knows nothing. Next!'.

Comment: You could go into MS Access work, Excel perhaps

Comment: do you work with "the web" or something?  simply try a different field

Comment: @sevensevens whats the point of this very unpleasant personally directed comment? You drop these comments often?

Comment: @user123557 when you see those types of comments clicking on the flag icon and selecting unfriendly or unkind is the correct response :)

Comment: Look to embedded systems, desktop application development or mobile application development. Really, if you want to avoid JS get away from web development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking at this wrong. You're not just paid to write code, you're paid to solve problems. What does it matter what programming language you're solving those problems in? Those same solutions can be applied to another programming language with just different syntax and libraries.

I also believe that you're looking at npm packages incorrectly. If you're always installing broken dependencies then you need to evaluate your dependencies better. A part of your job is ensuring that the packages you bring into the project are safe, maintained, and have an active list of contributors. Otherwise, you should look into a different package or see if your team wants to maintain it.

As far as the comment about "everyone and their grandma writes JS", well, sure it's very popular and that's why a lot of development is done in JavaScript now because companies don't have to worry about finding someone to fill a niche spot, they have access to a larger pool of developers.

You need to stop focusing so much on the language and what you think it means to employers. Employers aren't going to think that you're just a "script kiddo" if you have years of experience in a full stack JavaScript environment. If you think that finding another job is going to solve this problem, you're probably going to be disappointed when you realize that the problem isn't the language but your attitude about it.

Focus on solving problems, not just writing code, and you'll be valuable to any employer.

Comment: Thank you for this clearheaded answer, I really took something away from this. I'm staying put for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your company is focused entirely on using Javascript, and it appears that is the case, you have a couple of options:

1. See if you can influence the current technology stack at your present company to include some additional technologies.
2. Find another position at another company that uses a more diverse technology stack and be clear during your interview process that you want to be involved in technologies other than Javascript.

I think you will find it difficult these days to locate a company that does not use any Javascript.